# KALI Linux WiFi Adaptor Issues

Tags: wireless-networking, network-adapter

I have a TP-Link WN722N Adapter connected to my laptop, which runs Kali on a VirtualBox VM. The card is recognised, set up, and on monitor mode, can confirm with `iwconfig` and `airmon`.
However, as soon as I open something like Ghost Phisher, it still says

> Monitor Mode: Not Started

Any ideas?

edit: can confirm its almost a 'fake' monitor mode as [wifite also isn't recognising it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPXQK.png)

Comment: Is it in monitor mode in the VM or on the host?

Comment: In the VM, the adaptor gets disabled on the host when using it in the VM

Comment: Use the network card adapter (virtual adapter) provided by Virtual Box.  Go to the Kali network settings and make sure it is pointing to the Virtual Box adapter and not the HOST wireless adapter. I have Kali 2020 running as a VM in VMware Workstation as it works as I describe above.

Comment: This is what I have done, the card works fine, it might be an issue with ghost phisher itself

Answer (score 0):

Windows makes it very hard to put network adapters in monitor mode, it's actually not even worth it to attempt (trust me, I've tried for a very long time).  I would suggest creating a bootable USB with a live system or consider installing Kali on an empty partition of your drive.
However, if you must use monitor mode on Windows, you can try CommView

Comment: You can also use USB Pass-through and use a good USB wireless card which will work separately from the internal card

Comment: I would like to use the card on Kali, having the windows program won't make a difference surely?  Could it be an issue with Ghost Phisher instead of the card?

Comment: @JamesHyland do remember that you are on a virtual machine.  Windows has full control of your network hardware so it decides what can and cannot be done with it.  I've used many wireless networking tools in Kali that would not work on a Kali VM.